# Multiple annotations found at this line: - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fetch_user_info' in package

Tags: android, xml, facebook

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        facebook:confirm_logout="false"
        facebook:fetch_user_info="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="update_status" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/post_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="post_image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my login page for face i am getting Error :

```
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fetch_user_info' in package 
'com.example.facebookexmaple' 
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'confirm_logout' in package 
 'com.example.facebookexmaple'

at <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
```

while I have already added library and facebook name space please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Have you added gradle for facebook?

Comment: NO i am doing it in eclipse

Comment: its doesnot  working i have added that code also but this xml Error is not going

Answer (score 1):

At First, add `xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` instead `xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

For demo please check [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/getting-started-with-the-facebook-sdk-for-android/)

Comment: i have tired same but still same Error @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: okay then follow http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-implement-facebook-login-in-android-applications/

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment Give feedback after your checking

Comment: can u tell me how where i can get this facebook libarary ?

Comment: Yes ,Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377093/how-can-i-add-facebook-sdk-to-android-project

Comment: For my opinion please switch to android studio

Comment: actully i dont every work in Android Studio and i am doing some Live Project so i dont want to go

Comment: and i have still Error in FacebookSdk after adding androidsupportv4 and bolt.jar file